# I need to get my program to repeat and to total the orders

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that is suppose to ask for the type quantity and size of the lumber that is to be ordered. It is suppose to print the quantity, size, type and cost. Then the program is suppose to total the whole order. I am having a problem getting it to repeat and I have no idea how to get it to total the order.

```
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
char chr;
int main()
{
string order;
float P;
float F;
float C;
float M;
float O;
float T;
P=0.89;
F=1.09;
C=2.26;
M=4.50;
O=3.10;
float quantity=0;
float width=0;
float height=0;
float length=0;
char type;
float cost;
float bmeasure;
float total;
bmeasure=(width*height*length)/12;
char cont;
cout<<"Enter item: "<<endl;  // the user enters their order    
cin>>type>>quantity>>width>>height>>length;  //stores the information 
cost=bmeasure*quantity;  //calcualtes the cost 

if(type=='P')                                              //if the user orders pine
{
  bmeasure=(width*height*length)/12;                      //equation that converts the given measurement into board feet
  cost=bmeasure*quantity;                                 //calculates the cost 
cout<<quantity<<" "<<width<<"x"<<height<<"x"<<length<<" "<<"Pine"<<", "<<"cost: "<<"$"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost*.89<<endl; //prints out the users order with the price
}
else if(type=='F')                                         //if the user orders fir
{
     bmeasure=(width*height*length)/12;
     cost=bmeasure*quantity;
    cout<<quantity<<" "<<width<<"x"<<height<<"x"<<length<<" "<<"Fir"<<", "<<"cost: "<<"$"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost*1.09<<endl;
}
else if (type=='C')
{
    bmeasure=(width*height*length)/12;
  cost=bmeasure*quantity;
     cout<<quantity<<" "<<width<<"x"<<height<<"x"<<length<<" "<<"Cedar"<<", "<<"cost: "<<"$"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost*2.26<<endl;
}
else if(type=='M')
{
  bmeasure=(width*height*length)/12;
  cost=bmeasure*quantity;
    cout<<quantity<<" "<<width<<"x"<<height<<"x"<<length<<" "<<"Maple"<<", "<<"cost: "<<"$"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost*4.50<<endl;
}
else if (type=='O')
{
    bmeasure=(width*height*length)/12;
    cost=bmeasure*quantity;
    cout<<quantity<<" "<<width<<"x"<<height<<"x"<<length<<" "<<"Oak"<<", "<<"cost: "<<"$"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost*3.10<<endl;
}
else if (type=='T')
{
    cout<<"Total Cost: "<<total<<endl;
}

cout<<"Would you like to order more? Y or N"<<endl;  //user is asked if they would like to continue
cin>>cont;
{
if(cont=='n'||cont=='N')
   cout<<"Total: "<<endl;
}
cin>>chr;



return 0;
```

}

Comment: Do you know looping statements for, while, do-while ? Probably, do-while is more suitable for this task. Check for the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try and look at this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Look at the iterations sections.

Search around this sight for more info on how to use C++

cplusplus.com is full tutorials that explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything in a loop. Try putting all the if statement in a do-while loop that has the yes/no answer section controlling it.